# Adding animation on my svg, it changes its position

Tags: css, animation, svg, css-animations

I'm trying to add animation on some groups inside my svg, but after i add the animation my svg changes position. When i try to change it with position absolute tho it doesnt change.

In this code, I add the aimation to the group with the light class. I removed the rest of the code of the svg file so its more simple to show here.

My code:

```css
.svg-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: white;
}

.svg {
    padding-top: 40px;
}

.light {
    -webkit-animation: action 1s infinite;
    animation: action 1s infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes action {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
}

@keyframes action {
    0% {
        transform: translateY(0);
    }

    100% {
        transform: translateY(-10px);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-container">
            <div class="svg">
                <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="767.74" height="782.925">
                    <defs>
                        <linearGradient
                            id="a"
                            x1=".771"
                            y1=".879"
                            x2=".349"
                            y2=".103"
                            gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
                        >
                            <stop offset="0" stop-color="#ad81ff" />
                            <stop offset="1" stop-color="#ffe2ff" stop-opacity=".831" />
                        </linearGradient>
                        <linearGradient
                            id="b"
                            x1=".73"
                            y1=".875"
                            x2="-.036"
                            y2="-.615"
                            gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
                        >
                            <stop offset=".01" />
                            <stop offset=".13" stop-opacity=".69" />
                            <stop offset=".25" stop-opacity=".322" />
                            <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0" />
                        </linearGradient>
                        <linearGradient
                            id="c"
                            x1=".496"
                            y1="-1.57"
                            x2=".509"
                            y2="4.41"
                            gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox"
                        >
                            <stop offset=".01" />
                            <stop offset=".08" stop-opacity=".69" />
                            <stop offset=".21" stop-opacity=".322" />
                            <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0" />
                        </linearGradient>
                    </defs>
                    <path
                        data-name="Rectangle 3243"
                        fill="none"
                        opacity=".25"
                        d="M0 0h767.74v782.925H0z"
                    />
                    <rect
                        data-name="Rectangle 3237"
                        width="383.786"
                        height="416.279"
                        rx="26"
                        transform="translate(214.352 98.244)"
                        fill="url(#a)"
                    />
                    <g
                        class="light"
                        data-name="Group 1182"
                        transform="rotate(36 263.423 810.556)"
                    >
                        <path
                            data-name="Path 6006"
                            d="M58.972 24.627a24.534 24.534 0 0 1 1.64 16.443 27.256 27.256 0 0 0 .037 14.644c.441 1.455 1.049 2.858 1.624 4.394l-18.81 10.86c-.69-.871-1.333-1.77-2.059-2.6a25.313 25.313 0 0 0-11.728-7.54 30.7 30.7 0 0 1-10.886-5.525A26.052 26.052 0 0 1 19 15.332a25.956 25.956 0 0 1 1.66-1.241 25.9 25.9 0 0 1 38.308 10.53Z"
                            fill="#afb9c5"
                        />
                        <path
                            data-name="Path 6007"
                            d="M55.293 26.751a24.535 24.535 0 0 1 1.641 16.442 27.256 27.256 0 0 0 .036 14.644c.442 1.456 1.049 2.859 1.624 4.395l-15.13 8.736c-.692-.871-1.334-1.77-2.06-2.601a25.313 25.313 0 0 0-11.728-7.539 30.7 30.7 0 0 1-10.886-5.525A26.052 26.052 0 0 1 19 15.332c.545-.438 1.098-.86 1.66-1.242a25.651 25.651 0 0 1 6.154-2.017A25.934 25.934 0 0 1 55.293 26.75Z"
                            fill="#e4e8ec"
                        />
                        <circle
                            data-name="Ellipse 627"
                            cx="2.861"
                            cy="2.861"
                            transform="rotate(-30 137.783 -57.321)"
                            fill="#afb9c5"
                            r="2.861"
                        />
                        <path
                            data-name="Rectangle 2622"
                            fill="#afb9c5"
                            d="m32.468 31.618 1.12-.646 16.474 28.534-1.12.647z"
                        />
                        <path
                            data-name="Path 6029"
                            d="m31.023 33.105 4.85-2.8-5.21-3.245Z"
                            fill="#afb9c5"
                        />
                        <path
                            data-name="Path 6030"
                            d="m40.69 38.934-2.314 1.336-.675-1.168 2.315-1.337a2.6 2.6 0 0 0 .952-3.551l-1.04-1.802 1.166-.674 1.042 1.804a3.947 3.947 0 0 1-1.445 5.392Z"
                            fill="#afb9c5"
                        />
                        <path
                            data-name="Rectangle 2623"
                            fill="#afb9c5"
                            d="m37.35 30.887 3.728-2.152 2.153 3.728-3.729 2.152z"
                        />
                        <path
                            data-name="Path 6031"
                            d="m43.612 48.247-1.169.675-1.205-2.087a2 2 0 0 0-2.732-.732 3.947 3.947 0 0 1-5.386-1.446l-2.75-4.763 1.168-.675 2.764 4.788a2.6 2.6 0 0 0 3.552.952 3.344 3.344 0 0 1 4.565 1.223Z"
                            fill="#afb9c5"
                        />
                        <rect
                            data-name="Rectangle 2624"
                            width="4.305"
                            height="4.305"
                            rx="2.152"
                            transform="rotate(150 11.67 25.183)"
                            fill="#afb9c5"
                        />
                        <rect
                            data-name="Rectangle 2625"
                            width="27.208"
                            height="5.666"
                            rx="2.833"
                            transform="rotate(-30 155.273 -41.6)"
                            fill="#ced6dc"
                        />
                        <rect
                            data-name="Rectangle 2626"
                            width="24.321"
                            height="5.064"
                            rx="2.532"
                            transform="rotate(-30 163.695 -45.766)"
                            fill="#ced6dc"
                        />
                        <rect
                            data-name="Rectangle 2627"
                            width="21.102"
                            height="4.392"
                            rx="2.196"
                            transform="rotate(-30 170.605 -50.842)"
                            fill="#ced6dc"
                        />
                        <rect
                            data-name="Rectangle 2628"
                            width="27.208"
                            height="5.666"
                            rx="2.833"
                            transform="rotate(-30 155.273 -41.6)"
                            fill="#ced6dc"
                        />
                        <rect
                            data-name="Rectangle 2629"
                            width="24.321"
                            height="5.064"
                            rx="2.532"
                            transform="rotate(-30 163.695 -45.766)"
                            fill="#ced6dc"
                        />
                        <rect
                            data-name="Rectangle 2630"
                            width="21.102"
                            height="4.392"
                            rx="2.196"
                            transform="rotate(-30 170.605 -50.842)"
                            fill="#ced6dc"
                        />
                    </g>
                    
                </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Are you sure ? I have run it but in did not changing it's position, I belive some other element on page might affecting it's positon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem in you case is that the `g.light` element already has a `transform` property: `transform="rotate(36 263.423 810.556)"`. So the `action` animation is overwriting the default one that place the bulb icon in the top left.

My recommendation would be to separate the square and bulb in 2 different svg
and align them together by using `absolute` positioning:

```css
.svg-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: white;
}

.svg {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 40px;
}

.light {
  position: absolute;
  top: 7%;
  right: 30%;
  animation: action 1s infinite alternate;
}

@-webkit-keyframes action {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(40deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(40deg);
  }
}

@keyframes action {
  0% {
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(40deg);
  }

  100% {
    transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(40deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="svg-container">
  <div class="svg">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="767.74" height="782.925">
      <defs>
        <linearGradient id="a" x1=".771" y1=".879" x2=".349" y2=".103" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
          <stop offset="0" stop-color="#ad81ff" />
          <stop offset="1" stop-color="#ffe2ff" stop-opacity=".831" />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="b" x1=".73" y1=".875" x2="-.036" y2="-.615" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
          <stop offset=".01" />
          <stop offset=".13" stop-opacity=".69" />
          <stop offset=".25" stop-opacity=".322" />
          <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0" />
        </linearGradient>
        <linearGradient id="c" x1=".496" y1="-1.57" x2=".509" y2="4.41" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox">
          <stop offset=".01" />
          <stop offset=".08" stop-opacity=".69" />
          <stop offset=".21" stop-opacity=".322" />
          <stop offset="1" stop-opacity="0" />
        </linearGradient>
      </defs>
      <path data-name="Rectangle 3243" fill="none" opacity=".25" d="M0 0h767.74v782.925H0z" />
      <rect data-name="Rectangle 3237" width="383.786" height="416.279" rx="26" transform="translate(214.352 98.244)" fill="url(#a)" />
    </svg>
    <svg class="light" width="70" heigth="73">
      <g data-name="Group 1182">
        <path data-name="Path 6006" d="M58.972 24.627a24.534 24.534 0 0 1 1.64 16.443 27.256 27.256 0 0 0 .037 14.644c.441 1.455 1.049 2.858 1.624 4.394l-18.81 10.86c-.69-.871-1.333-1.77-2.059-2.6a25.313 25.313 0 0 0-11.728-7.54 30.7 30.7 0 0 1-10.886-5.525A26.052 26.052 0 0 1 19 15.332a25.956 25.956 0 0 1 1.66-1.241 25.9 25.9 0 0 1 38.308 10.53Z" fill="#afb9c5" />
        <path data-name="Path 6007" d="M55.293 26.751a24.535 24.535 0 0 1 1.641 16.442 27.256 27.256 0 0 0 .036 14.644c.442 1.456 1.049 2.859 1.624 4.395l-15.13 8.736c-.692-.871-1.334-1.77-2.06-2.601a25.313 25.313 0 0 0-11.728-7.539 30.7 30.7 0 0 1-10.886-5.525A26.052 26.052 0 0 1 19 15.332c.545-.438 1.098-.86 1.66-1.242a25.651 25.651 0 0 1 6.154-2.017A25.934 25.934 0 0 1 55.293 26.75Z" fill="#e4e8ec" />
        <circle data-name="Ellipse 627" cx="2.861" cy="2.861" transform="rotate(-30 137.783 -57.321)" fill="#afb9c5" r="2.861" />
        <path data-name="Rectangle 2622" fill="#afb9c5" d="m32.468 31.618 1.12-.646 16.474 28.534-1.12.647z" />
        <path data-name="Path 6029" d="m31.023 33.105 4.85-2.8-5.21-3.245Z" fill="#afb9c5" />
        <path data-name="Path 6030" d="m40.69 38.934-2.314 1.336-.675-1.168 2.315-1.337a2.6 2.6 0 0 0 .952-3.551l-1.04-1.802 1.166-.674 1.042 1.804a3.947 3.947 0 0 1-1.445 5.392Z" fill="#afb9c5" />
        <path data-name="Rectangle 2623" fill="#afb9c5" d="m37.35 30.887 3.728-2.152 2.153 3.728-3.729 2.152z" />
        <path data-name="Path 6031" d="m43.612 48.247-1.169.675-1.205-2.087a2 2 0 0 0-2.732-.732 3.947 3.947 0 0 1-5.386-1.446l-2.75-4.763 1.168-.675 2.764 4.788a2.6 2.6 0 0 0 3.552.952 3.344 3.344 0 0 1 4.565 1.223Z" fill="#afb9c5" />
        <rect data-name="Rectangle 2624" width="4.305" height="4.305" rx="2.152" transform="rotate(150 11.67 25.183)" fill="#afb9c5" />
        <rect data-name="Rectangle 2625" width="27.208" height="5.666" rx="2.833" transform="rotate(-30 155.273 -41.6)" fill="#ced6dc" />
        <rect data-name="Rectangle 2626" width="24.321" height="5.064" rx="2.532" transform="rotate(-30 163.695 -45.766)" fill="#ced6dc" />
        <rect data-name="Rectangle 2627" width="21.102" height="4.392" rx="2.196" transform="rotate(-30 170.605 -50.842)" fill="#ced6dc" />
        <rect data-name="Rectangle 2628" width="27.208" height="5.666" rx="2.833" transform="rotate(-30 155.273 -41.6)" fill="#ced6dc" />
        <rect data-name="Rectangle 2629" width="24.321" height="5.064" rx="2.532" transform="rotate(-30 163.695 -45.766)" fill="#ced6dc" />
        <rect data-name="Rectangle 2630" width="21.102" height="4.392" rx="2.196" transform="rotate(-30 170.605 -50.842)" fill="#ced6dc" />
      </g>
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I never thought about this. This worked for me!